# Spring - Hibernate ManyToMany in Restful app

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, many-to-many, http-status-code-404

i have my spring app running with two entities Article and Category.

I integrated RestResponses and it works all fine. Next i added a ManyToMany Relationship to these entities and my rest responses return 404.

I will show you my configuration:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `articles`;
create table `articles` (
    `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `categories`;
create table `categories` (
    `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `categories_articles`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories_articles` (
    `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `categoryID` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `articleID` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `categoryArticleID` (`categoryID`, `articleID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `categories_articles`
ADD CONSTRAINT `categories_articles_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`categoryID`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `categories_articles_fk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`articleID`) REFERENCES `articles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Article.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "articles")
public class Article {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    private List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();

    public Article() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "articles")
    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

}
```

Category.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    private List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<Article>();

    public Category() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "categories_articles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "categoryID", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "articleID", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    public List<Article> getArticles() {
        return articles;
    }

    public void setArticles(List<Article> articles) {
        this.articles = articles;
    }

}
```

And my RestController:

```
@GetMapping("/rest/categories")
public RestResponse<Category> list() {
    List<Category> data = categoryService.list();
    RestResponse<Category> restResponse = new RestResponse<Category>(true, data.size(), data);
    return restResponse;
}
```

where RestResponse is just a simple PoJo:

```
public class RestResponse<T> {

    private Boolean success;

    private Integer count;

    private List<T> data;

    public RestResponse(Boolean success, Integer count, List<T> data) {
        this.success = success;
        this.count = count;
        this.data = data;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Sooo, as soon as i comment the *many-to-many* part and load my app, it all works fine.. but when i uncomment the *many-to-many* part, i get 404..

I have no idea why, could anybody help me with this issue?

thanks and greetings!

Comment: try to add full stacktrace. Also add the transactional method where the error occurs.. unless it is during startup.

Comment: there is no full stacktrace, in browser its just: HTTP Status 404 - /rest/categories...or what do you mean?

Comment: It seems that the server is not starting because of some error regarding that mapping.. try to find the startup logs

Comment: hey, last logs:

Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M11

Deploying web application archive /path/app.war

it looks all fine.. where else can i look?

Comment: Do you get any error when invoking List<Category> data = categoryService.list();?

Comment: oh yes thanks! i didnt see i mapped annotation to method and not property..thanks..